# Pass method reference instead of delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

when calling the method:

```
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( someDelegate  , parameters);
```

I need to create the someDelegate pointer. I know how to create the delegate and then pass it with this function. A delegate is just a pointer to a method so it will be nice if I can pass the reference. In other words I don't know if it is possible to do simething like:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( someMethod.reference, parameters);

public void someMethod(object o)
{
  // ....
}
```

Or something like:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( ()=> {

   //method

 }, parameters);
```

I require to use multiple threads therefore it will be nice if I do not have to create that many delegates. It will be nice if I could create them on the fly inside of the method...

Comment: From a performance standpoint, I doubt you need to be concerned about the overhead of creating delegate instances...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action(()=> {
   //method
 }), parameters);
```